# Remove row from dataframe if column value

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, dataframe, filter

If I have a dataframe like this:

```
index   col1   col2 
a        a1     a2
b        b1     b2
c        c1     b2
```

Is it possible to use the `.drop()` to delete rows which have a sudden value in one of their columns?

Something like: `df.drop(col2 = 'b2')`

Answer (score 5):

You need [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df[df.col2 != 'b2']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a boolean filter. For example:

```
df = df[df['col1'] != 'a1']
```

Would drop all rows with the value a1 in column col1. See [this page of the Pandas docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) for more details.